# Is there a way to add a query paramater inside a StreamProvider

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Flutter application with a Firebase back end. I have a list of documents in a collection that I am fetching using QuerySnapshots.

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get data{
   return dataCollection
    .snapshots();
    }
```

I then use the data in a StreamProvider like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value(
      value: QueryService().data,
      initialData: null,
      child: Scaffold(
      body: ItemList()
     )
   );
```

The item List is:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot?>(context);
    if (data!= null) {
      for (var doc in data.docs) {
        print(doc.data());
      }
    } else {
      print('No Data');
    }

    return Container();
  }
```

If I was to filter out, I would do something like this:

```
      Stream<QuerySnapshot> get data{
       return dataCollection
         .where('someField', isEqualTo: 'accepted')
         .snapshots();
      }
```

But this is a case in which I want to use the data stream in several widgets and the filter parameters will vary. Is there a way I can filter them at the Provider level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve specific fields like this.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDataField(String field, String value){
   return dataCollection
     .where(field, isEqualTo: value)
     .snapshots();
}
```

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for, can you please mark it as accepted?